# Ruby case statement with regexe matching

Tags: ruby, regex, switch-statement

I'm working on my second ruby program and am stuck on literally the last thing standing between me and a completed program.  My task is to write a Rock, Paper, Scissors Method that returns the winning player.  To do this it takes a game argument in the form of [["Dave","S"], ["Dan","R"]], where "S" and "R" are "Scissors" and "Rock" respectively.  It then determines the winner and returns the array that contained the winning strategy.  Also Raises Errors if game is wrong length or strategies are == or not in range.

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError < StandardError ; end
class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError ; end


def rps_game_winner(game)

raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError unless game.length == 2

  #Hash of whose Keys are the strategies and values are the players
  playr = {(game[0].slice(1).downcase) => game[0],
    (game[1].slice(1).downcase) => game[1]} #This fits on the above line in IRB

  #Collect Strategies in array for comparison
  stgys = playr.keys

  #raise NoSuchStrategyError unless players give strategies in range, no duplicates
  raise NoSuchStrategyError unless (stgys.select { |s| s.match /[prs]/ }.size == 2) 

  #determine Winner
  case stgys.to_s
   when /p/ && /r/
     playr["p"]
   when /p/ && /s/
     playr["s"]
   when /s/ && /r/
     playr["r"]
  end
end
```

This works as I expect, checking the strategies against the regexes and returning the winner.  Except the last case, where when met always returns nil.  If I call player["r"] under either of the other whens it succeeds, and it returns the right player in "/p/ && /r/".  If I change the order, it still doesn't work so I know it doesn't have to do with its position.  The regex /r/ evaluates when it should if I make a separate match call outside the case statement.  So I believe I've narrowed it down to something to do with how /s/ and /r/ relate but otherwise I'm stumped.  Also any help with DRYness is appreciated, Thanks for the Help!

Comment: seems to be a homework from saas class  :)

Comment: You know it, started late hoping to catch up but after beating my head against the code for hours on this one I realized Armando might not have been joking about it being a Senior level course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you do not need `case` at all.
My version of solution for that task:

```
def rps_game_winner(game)
  raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError unless game.length == 2
  raise NoSuchStrategyError if game.any? {|n| !(n[1] =~ /^[spr]$/i)}
  loose_hash = {'s' => 'r', 'p' => 's', 'r' => 'p'}
  strategy1 = game[0][1].downcase
  strategy2 = game[1][1].downcase
  loose_hash[strategy1] == strategy2 ? game[1] : game[0]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, being new to ruby I wasn't familiar with the ?: conditional that you deployed so well here and as a novice programmer I like using the hash  but really don't know how to fully utilize it.  Your loose_hash makes so much sense when I look at your method but I wouldn't have thought of it.  Thanks for helping me become a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `/X/ && /X/` format.  Ruby won't interpret that as requiring both regexes to match.  I'm not certain which, but I believe it will treat it the same as `when /p/, /r/`, which will be true if *either* regex matches.  When you test `game = [["Dave","S"], ["Dan","R"]]`, the `"r"` matches the first case statement, and you try to reference `playr["p"]`.

Try this instead:

```
case stgys.to_S
  when "pr", "rp"
    playr["p"]
  when "ps", "sp"
    playr["s"]
  when "sr", "rs"
    playr["r"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately when I input this it doesn't work because .to_s returns a representation of self not the string elements in other words "[\"p\", \"r\"]".  I ended up letting go of my dry ambitions and added .sort to the call for the hash keys and then using the three possible strings that could result as my 'when' arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `/p/ && /r/` is evaluated before it's actually used as the label. Since neither of those is false or nil, `/p/ && /r/` is equal to `/r/`, and similarly for your other case labels.

Unless you rewrite this to have a single case statement for each case, it seems to me that `case` just isn't a very good fit for what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

With the help of instructions in the problem, I have solved the problem in a different way.

```
def rps_game_winner(game)
  raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError unless game.length == 2
  raise NoSuchStrategyError unless game[0].length == 2 and game[1].length == 2
  raise NoSuchStrategyError unless game[0][1] =~ /^[RPS]$/ and game[1][1] =~ /^[RPS]$/
  return game[0] unless (game[0][1] == "P" and game[1][1] == "S") or
                        (game[0][1] == "S" and game[1][1] == "R") or
                        (game[0][1] == "R" and game[1][1] == "P")
  return game[1]
end

def rps_tournament_winner(tournament)
  return rps_game_winner(tournament) unless tournament[0][1] !~ /^[RPS]$/
  return rps_tournament_winner([rps_tournament_winner(tournament[0]), rps_tournament_winner(tournament[1])])
end
```

I have tested all the given scenarios and it worked for me.